# ReachJS Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tr>. Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace between tags on each line of

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting **Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of . Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace between tags on each line of your source code.** when I'm trying to implement table with materialUI in ReactJS. Erro says white space found in code line around **< TableRow..**  But I can't find any white space in error line.

```
return (
  <>
    <TableRow
      key={this.props.data.id}
      className="simpleProductRow align-top">
      <TableCell className="simpleProductInfo simpleProductCell">
        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
          <Typography
            variant="body2"
            component="label"
            style={inlineBlockStyle}
          >
            Info:{' '}
          </Typography>
          <Typography className="simpleProductName" component="span">
            {this.props.data.name}
          </Typography>
        </Typography>

        <Typography variant="body2" component="span">
          <Typography variant="body2" style={inlineBlockStyle}>
            Part #:{' '}
          </Typography>
          <Typography style={inlineBlockStyle}>
            {this.props.data.sku}
          </Typography>
          <Typography style={inlineBlockStyleSmall}>
            (Mfr #: {this.props.data.manufacturerPartNumber})
          </Typography>
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
          <Typography
            variant="body2"
            component="label"
            style={inlineBlockStyle}
          >
            Ships:{' '}
          </Typography>
          <Typography style={inlineBlockStyle} component="span">
            {' '}
            {this.props.data.deliveryDate}
          </Typography>
        </Typography>

        {this.props &&
          this.props.data &&
          this.props.data.isFreeShipping && (
            <Chip
              className={this.props.classes.freeShippingChip}
              label="Free Shipping"
              avatar={freeshippingavatar}
            />
          )}
      </TableCell>{' '}

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell colSpan={4}>
        <ProductSpecifications data={this.props && this.props.data} />
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Isanka, I know it is a long time ago, but is it possible that your error message:
"...appear as a child of . Make..."  actually contained a tag just before the full stop?
The error message I received (see my answer below) was:
"...appear as a child of **<tr>**. Make..."
The addition of a missing tag may help people to locate this question/answer more quickly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Near the end of your code example you have:

`</TableCell>{' '}`

You need to remove the `{' '}` at the end.  It is a “whitespace text node”.

Answer (score 2):

In my case

```
<tr>
<th></th> <th></th>
</tr>
```

a space between `</th>` `<th>` made a warning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I use useState like this, it gives the same error.

```
const [items,setItems] = useState("");
```

To get rid of this, I had to make it like this

```
const [items,setItems] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue, but luckily my error message was

> Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of **<tr>**.

Which allowed me to look for a problem with <tr> entries.  It was obvious when I saw it as my code was:

`<tr>  </tr>`

Having two spaces between the tags.